# How to return data from JQuery GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, settimeout

I made a function that runs a get request using JQuery.
But I need the get to return this received value to the calling function. function

```
gettime() {

var timeOut =0;


    $.get("http://localhost:8080/t.html", function( data )
         {

               timeOut = data*1000;
               return timeOut;
         });


    //retun(timeOut);
 }
```

I want the value received by get to be returned to the main function that calls gettime()
please help out. 
It's a integer am passing.

Answer (score 1):

An idea could be implementing a callback:

```
function gettime(callback) {
    var timeOut =0;

    $.get("http://localhost:8080/t.html", function(data)
    {
        timeOut = data*1000;
        callback(timeOut);
    });
}

//Then you can retrieve that value by doing this:

gettime(function(timeout){
    //Do your stuff here.
});
```

Comment: Its causing a error, "callback is not a function"

Comment: How do you call the gettime function?